# Обновить таблицу по условию из другой

Tags: sql, foxpro

Есть таблица `tmp` с полями `id, d1, d2`. Также есть таблица `tmp2` с полем `tmpid` связаны они по полю `tmp.id = tmp2.tmpid`

Как обновить в таблице `tmp` поле `d1` только для тех записей, которые есть в `tmp2` ?

```
UPDATE Tmp SET d1 = 'No' WHERE tmp.id = tmp2.tmpid
```

такой запрос почему-то обновляет малую часть лишь 10 записей из Tmp у которых одинаковый `id`

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то

```sql
update Tmp from tmp2 where Tmp.id = tmp2 .tmpid ;
set Tmp.d1 = 'No'
```

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE Tmp SET d1 = 'No' WHERE tmp.id = tmp2.tmpid

Можете использовать join в апдейте.

```
update tmp t1
  join tmp2 t2 on t1.id = t2.tmpid
set t1.d1 = 'No';
```

Таким образом обновятся только те записи, которые прошли join.